# Edit Geometry with digitizing tools in QGIS of a postgis layer

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, digitizing

I have a multiline PostGIS layer added to my QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa. I'm able to add features using the digitizing tools, but I'm not able to use the delete or node tool. It remains gray even if I'm in editing mode. Every thing works fine on a temporary layer. Does anyone has a clue why I can't edit?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue - we run into this. Or lack of a primary key or objectID that can be recognized by PostgreSQL / PostGIS... are you able to 'save' your edits after you add new features?

Comment: Yes saving did work even in version 2.10.1

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded my qgis to version 2.0.1, now it works. It seems to be a bug in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your database table is missing a primary key - this prevents modification or deletion of features, but allows addition.